# Gurantee context for kubectl command - "kubectl get po use-context bla"?

Tags: kubectl

I am writing a script which involves `kubectl delete` , it is of course existential to run in against correct context-cluster.

The problem is that from what I observe, if you open two terminals and do:

```
kubectl config use-context bla
```

in one window, then the other one will switch as well. Therefore, concern if something switches context during script execution my delete operation will start deleting resources in the wrong cluster.

I understand that I could use labels on my pods or different namespaces, but in my case namespaces are the same and there are no labels.

So is there a way to specify for each command individually which context it should execute against? Something like:

```
kubectl get po use-context bla
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `--context` flag:

```
kubectl get po --context bla
```

If you run any `kubectl` command, you'll also see it says you can run `kubectl options` to see a list of global options that can be applied to any command. `--context` is one such global option.